# Search function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am new to rails and have been following the Hartl rails tutorial. I have added a profile model for the user, and now want to be able to find a user via an attribute in the profile model. I have looked at numerous tutorials and questions on Stack Overflow, but can't seem to get it working, I would very much appreciate any assistance.
I have added the search form to static_pages/home.html.erb as follows;

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Enter  your doctor's medical registration number" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Connect with your doctor", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Updated my routes.rb

```
get '/search', to: 'users#search'
```

Added a search method to the users controller

```
def search
  @user = User.joins(:profile).where("profile.medicno" => params[:search])
end
```

And created a search.html.erb view

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
```

Everything seems to be working but it is not returning the user, am I missing something?

Comment: firstly check what you got `@user` in `def search` method

Comment: I added debugger into the search method and it says Return value is: nil

Comment: I tried both plural version below and still not returning the user

Comment: you are not getting any data from `db`

Comment: it seems not, any ideas on why?

Comment: try this on `Rails console` `User.joins(:profile).where("profile.medicno" => 'that value which exist in db')` and see what is the output

Comment: still nothing, this is the output :002?>

Comment: sorry just ran it again and got this; User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "profile"."medicno" = ? LIMIT ?  [["medicno", "that value which exist in db"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profile.medicno: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "profile"."medicno" = ? LIMIT ?

Comment: try `profiles.medicno` instead `profile.medicno`. run this from console `@user = User.joins(:profile).where("profiles.medicno" => Profile.last.medicno)` and let us know the response

Comment: Yes this returning the user but it is not showing in the view 
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 10, name: "Doctor Search Test", email: "doctor@doctor.ie", created_at: "2018-04-13 11:18:47", updated_at: "2018-04-13 11:19:07", password_digest: "$2a$10$G4b9d3aIbbkXJjWsQNYIuuBxBKpvMOUOws7SWDBhglc...", remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: "$2a$10$qHSytBWFGAHOzgRC0G1m1.SoNo55PIZJxhZAGMUhM5H...", activated: true, activated_at: "2018-04-13 11:19:07", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, identity: 1>]>

Comment: When you use `.where` a collection will be returned. You can chain `.first` to the end then `@user` will be one instance of `User`

Comment: Fantastic, it worked!!! Thanks for all of your help guys!